# How to portably avoid tox failures caused by temporary python files?

Tags: python, pytest, tox

While using tox and pytest to test python code one would sooner or later encounter execution failures caused by presence of some `.pyc` or `.pyo` temporary files.

One common approach is to disable their generation like below but this is not work if the user may even one accidentally run code outside tox.

```
setenv =
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

Another approach I seen used quite often is to add cleanup commands before triggering the tests on `commands` section or the newer one `command_pres`, like below:

```
commands_pre =
    find {toxinidir} -type f -not -path '{toxinidir}/.tox/*' -path '*/__pycache__/*' -name '*.py[c|o]' -delete
```

Even so the code below has few drawbacks too:
  * not fully portable (will clearly not work for Windows users)
  * is slow, it adds few seconds to each run
  * is ugly and hard to disseminate across projects

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this that is faster and more portable?

Comment: Best is IMO not to run `tox` over source code in repository at all and switch to the `src` layout. `tox` will build a source dist and install it for every environment anyway, so there's not much left to configure for testing the installed code.